# What's the difference between /var/spool/cron and /var/spool/cron/crontabs?

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-task, incrontab

This went unmentoned anywhere else I could find, not even in the man page of crontab. what's the difference between them?

some people say they don't have /var/spool/cron/crontabs, but one can easily find lots of systems with this path. for example, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7229/6j6q8svfo/index.html).

note here I'm not talking about one specific linux distro, if these two paths come from different distros, I would like to know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your distro.

On Fedora I can see only /var/spool/cron and the man for cron says:

`/var/spool/cron
              directory that contains user crontables created by the crontab command.`

I can't find /var/spool/cron/crontabs.

On other systems (Maybe Debian) the crontabs dir is the same as the cron dir.